# how to verify if there is an especific instance on two lists without one of them fails the verification?

Tags: java, list

```
String nomeU = sc.next();
int k = 0;
for(User u : user) {
    if(u.nameUser.contentEquals(nameU)) {
        k = k + 1;
    }
}
int h = 0;
for(Associa a : asso) {
    if(a.nameA.contentEquals(nameU)) {
        h = h + 1;
    }
}
if(k == 0) {
    System.out.println("nonexistent user.");
    break jump;
}
if(h == 0) {
    System.out.println("nonexistent user.");
    break jump;
}
```

So basically a "user" it's a pacient of an hospital and the list user has the names in it.

In the asso list i have users that are associated with a family name like John Smith.

So when i associate a user with a family, i remove them from the user list and add them to the asso list.

And here what i want is to verify if the name of the input is in one of those lists but what i have here will give "nonexistent user." as output if there is no user with that name in the user list even if there is in the asso list.

how can i verify them both and if only both fail??

Comment: You are pretty close... if `k` is `0`, then the user is not in the `user` list; if `h` is `0`, then the user is not in the `asso` list. What condition, in terms of `k` and `h` must be true, if the user is in neither of these lists?

Comment: i thought of  (k == 0 || h == 0)

Comment: Try formulating it in words first, not in code.

Comment: if k is 0 and h is 0 then the condition is true.

Comment: Yes. But `||` is a logical OR. You ar looking for the logical AND, `&&`.

Comment: yes but i already tried using the logical AND but it didn't work :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206172/discussion-between-turing85-and-filipe-mota).

Comment: ohh i saw the problem now!! it wan in the other part of the code sorry!